# Sort Part Numbers by First Character in Excel

Tags: excel, sorting

I have an excel document with about 12,000 lines of part numbers with pricing information. I think the most intuitive way to sort them would be as follows:

1, 12, 15, 100, 10003, 2, 2002, 20005000, 3, 30, 333, 4, 5, 6, 700000, 800000.

All the numbers that begin with 1 are in the same spot, same with all 2 prefixes, etc. My problem is, excel's default sorting method sorts it like THIS:

1, 20, 30, 40, 100, 150, 200, 250, 500, 1000, 1500, 2000, 10000.

So it sorts them in regular ascending order, which I think makes it more difficult to find your part number, especially as they get super long as some of them do.

I don't have a lot of resources outside of excel at my workspace, so I would like to stick to using that. My knowledge of excel also isn't too impressive, so please treat me like an idiot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make thing easier to describe, let's assume that your list of part numbers is in column A, and that you have a blank column B.

In cell B2 enter this formula:

```
=TEXT(A1,"#")
```

Copy that down as far as your list goes.

Now, selecting both columns, Custom Sort **by** column B.

That's it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I got it working now :)

Answer (score 0):

Create a new column called `SortOrder` with the following formula:

```
=VALUE(LEFT(A2,1))
```

Then go to **Home** tab > **Sort & Filter** > **Custom Sort...**. Sort first by `SortOrder`, then by `Value`:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I got it working now :)

Answer (score 0):

With data in column **A** like:

[image]

In **B1** enter:

```
=CHAR(1) & A1
```

and copy down.  Then sort cols **A** & **B** by **B** to get:

[image]

Is this "alphabetic-style" sort closer to what you need??

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I got it working now :)

Comment: @Mikee  Thanks for the feedback!